# What is this C syntax (used in Linux drivers/net/bonding/bond_main.c)?

Tags: c, linux, syntax

I've written plenty of C before, but I don't recognize this syntax:

```
static const char *names[] = {
    [BOND_MODE_ROUNDROBIN] = "load balancing (round-robin)",
    [BOND_MODE_ACTIVEBACKUP] = "fault-tolerance (active-backup)",
    [BOND_MODE_XOR] = "load balancing (xor)",
    [BOND_MODE_BROADCAST] = "fault-tolerance (broadcast)",
    [BOND_MODE_8023AD] = "IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation",
    [BOND_MODE_TLB] = "transmit load balancing",
    [BOND_MODE_ALB] = "adaptive load balancing",
};
```

The `[...] =` part is what looks weird to me. (By the way, `BOND_MODE_ROUNDROBIN` and the others are macros which just expand to integers.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called **designated initializers**, which is introduced in C99. GCC also supports it as an extension.

It's used to initialize structures and arrays, see [Designated Initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) for detail.

Comment: Cool. So no matter what the specific `#define`d values are, they will always appear in the array in the correct order.

Comment: +1, it extends my knowledge of designated initializers on struct members, cool.

Comment: +1 new for me.really helpful. I see this type code used in kernel coding.

Answer (score 4):

That is a [**designated initializer**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). It allows you to intialize the contents of the array in an arbitrary order.

Answer (score 0):

Here names is the array of char pointes.

These pointers are pointing to the string stored in read only section.

And Initilizing is done using **Designated Initializers** methods.

SO here you can initilize any array with any order of their index.
Those macros are index of array.